# Shader and Texture Scrolling depending on Direction

Tags: unity, shaders, glsl, hlsl, cg

I am trying to scroll a texture using its uv in Unity but I don't get the result I need.

The aim is to have two components, the speed and the direction. I would like to define the direction in normalized values and the speed should influence the velocity of the scrolling according to the direction.

If I change the speed at runtime, I don't want to have some hiccups but maybe this should not be handled but the GPU.

How can I do that in a better way, maybe using matrix ?

Here is an example but the result is not as good as expected.

```
uv.xy = uv.xy + frac(_Time.y * float2(_Direction.x, _Direction.y));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control texture UV with external code.
Define `uniform float4 _Diffuse_ST;` in your shader and then in your script call it every Update():

```cs
public float rollSpeed = 0.1f;

void Update()
{
    offset += Time.deltaTime * rollSpeed;
    renderer.material.SetTextureOffset("_Diffuse", new Vector2(offset, 0));
}
```

Then your shader will look like this (it also rotates the texture, but you can remove this code):

```
Shader "Custom/TextureRotation"
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Diffuse("_Diffuse", 2D) = "black" {}
    }

    SubShader 
    {                   
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM       

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0          

            sampler2D _Diffuse;
            float4x4 _Rotation;
            uniform float4 _Diffuse_ST;

            struct vertexInput
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;               
                float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;               
            };

            struct vertexOutput
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                half2 col : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct Input
            {               
                float2 uv_Diffuse;
            };

            vertexOutput vert(vertexInput input)
            {
                vertexOutput output;

                output.pos =  mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, input.vertex);
                output.col =  input.texcoord.xy *_Diffuse_ST.xy + _Diffuse_ST.zw;               
                return output;
            }

            float4 frag (vertexOutput IN) : COLOR
            {           
                float4 MxV0=mul( _Rotation, (IN.col.xyxy) );
                return tex2D(_Diffuse,MxV0.xy);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```